# Django RedirectView CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django

I ran into a problem when redirecting a request through RedirectView. It returns a `403 CSRF verification failed Request aborted` response. Why?

Here are the contents of my `project/urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('v2/partner/products/groups', RedirectView.as_view(url=f"{abm_url.ABM_URL}/v2/partner/products/groups"))]
```

Comment: if your submitting form then you have to set {% csrf_token %} in form tag in html

Comment: I don't use html form, I just want to send a request to another server via redirectview in urls.py

Comment: Can you please show your views?

Comment: make it a GET request or include csrf_token using javascript in your POST view

Comment: Wariored, ANFAS PV, RedirectView from django.view.generic, this is an inline view in django